# typeface won't appear correctly

Tags: android

in my android application I've set a typeface in some textViews while in my mobile and in my nexus 7'' everything is shown properly the same won't happen when I install my application in galaxy tab2 7''. what could be wrong?

```
        typeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Ubuntu.ttf");
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText(literals.get(0));
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setTypeface(typeFace);
```

Comment: How do you set the Typeface, and what format is the typeface?

Answer (score 2):

There is an amazing Android library [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) to deal with custom fonts. Give it a try.

Comment: ok but I don't want to use an extra library for this..I'm just asking if it is an issue with tab2 or possibly my mistake...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a device issue, We have the same issue where files inside the Assets are just not bundled onto the device.

I don't any solid solutions unfortunately.

I could maybe suggest another font. As some of the older (buggier) version of android may not read Typefaces correctly. Try the Roboto font from google, if that doesn't work on that specific device, it is almost 100% that device playing up.

Answer (score -1):

Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/my_font.ttf");
myTextview.setTypeface(typeface);

Comment: what Did I do differently?